robot_localization not applying corrective measurement (GPS)
I am a beginner building a mobile outdoor robot using robot_localization and navsat_transform_node. My current setup is to use the ZED2 odom->base_link for relative localization and a robot_localization fusing ZED2+GPS for the map->odom link. I am scaling up the covariance of the ZED2 odom output into /zed2/zed_node/odom/scaled since it reports very low values. My main problem however is that the /odometry/filtered output doesn't seem to be taking in the GPS corrections and is simply adhering to the zed2 odom. I also have a rosbag available if that would help (not sure how to upload it here though)
ekf_localization:
frequency: 10 
   
odom0: "/odometry/gps"
odom0_config: [true, true, false,
               false, false, false, 
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false]

odom0_differential: false 
odom0_queue_size: 10
odom0_nodelay: false

odom1: "/zed2/zed_node/odom/scaled"
odom1_config: [true, true, true,
               true, true, true, 
               false, false, false, 
               false, false, false,
               false, false, false]
odom1_differential: true 
publish_tf: true 
two_d_mode: true      
zero_altitude: true
odom1_queue_size: 10

transform_time_offset: 0.0
sensor_timeout: 0.1

print_diagnostics: true

/odometry/gps message:
header: 
  seq: 88
  stamp: 
    secs: 1715040885
    nsecs: 999999941
  frame_id: "map"
child_frame_id: ''
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -1.8082647579722106
      y: 6.78674371377565
      z: 0.0
    orientation: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
      w: 1.0
  covariance: [10.329796, -7.638623819165389e-16, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.800402657245562e-16, 10.329796, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 52.911076, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

zed2 message:
header: 
  seq: 3051
  stamp: 
    secs: 1714862760
    nsecs: 820313376
  frame_id: "odom"
child_frame_id: "base_link"
pose: 
  pose: 
    position: 
      x: -2.2758363942759643
      y: -3.6461416012254793
      z: 2.54802149433537
    orientation: 
      x: -0.10131179962388726
      y: -0.04599926700586338
      z: 0.76016454488177
      w: 0.640132682650569
  covariance: [25.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 25.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 25.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
twist: 
  twist: 
    linear: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
    angular: 
      x: 0.0
      y: 0.0
      z: 0.0
  covariance: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]


I would recommend explicitly setting your world_frame parameter, but that's just for clarity when asking questions. It defaults to the value of your odom_frame parameter (which you also didn't set), which defaults to odom.
Anyway, your EKF instance believes it is estimating your pose in the odom frame. It receives a message from your zed2, and sees that the frame_id of that message (which refers to the frame of the pose data therein) is set to odom. Since the EKF is working in that frame for pose data, it can fuse that measurement directly. Great!
Now it receives a GPS odometry message. The frame_id is set to map. You have not provided a transform from map to odom, so the EKF has to idea how to transform from the frame ID of the message to the frame ID of the EKF. So it ignores the message.
This is why we typically recommend a two-tier setup in which the first instance is estimating the odom->base_link transform, and the second instance is generating map->odom. I haven't looked at the r_l wiki in a while, but I'm pretty sure I have that use case called out explicitly. There should also be numerous examples floating around other questions, and the config templates likely call it out.
So you can either run a second instance with the world_frame set to map, or you can fix your navsat_transform_node output so it's generating a message in the odom frame.
Also, you have two_d_mode enabled, but you are passing in 3D variables to the filter. This doesn't matter (the filter ignores them), but it makes for a confusing config file.
